# Have an item be zoomable and swipable?

Tags: canvas, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have an "canvas" Item (not HTML-like canvas, just a plain Item with a hundred+ of children) whose children are all a picture, and all are ordered in a grid-like layout by Javascript at creation time, and recreated at canvas resize.
The width/height ratio of the canvas is not constant (well, once everything is drawn, it is), so I'd like to be able to put it in a "container" where we could zoom/unzoom in it or wipe to go to the bottom of the canvas.

Is there a QtQuick type for this ? I've come across Canvas, Context 2D, etc., but I don't find a solution that does NOT involve drawing through JS (well, if it's the only way, I could rewrite my renderer). I'm looking for something that interanlly use something like a 3x3 matrix to translate and scale things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the answer is No. The only approach to scale canvas is to call the canvas's scale method:

```
object scale(real x, real y)
```